# how to deal with NA in ifelse?

Tags: r

Assuming we have this:

```
x=5
y=NA
x1=8
y1=NA
ifelse(x < y, x1, y1)
[1] NA
```

as one of them is NA, I want ifelse to return the value.
so desired output for this case:

```
 ifelse(x < y, x1, y1)
  [1] 8
```

Comment: And if `x` is NA you want `x1` returned? What if both are `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifelse(any(is.na(x),is.na(y)),
  c(x1,y1)[c(!is.na(x),!is.na(y))],
  ifelse(x < y, x1, y1))
```

First we check if there are any NAs, if there are, we return the answer that matches the one that isn't NA. If there are no NAs, we run the original ifelse written by OP.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using `is.na` here:

```
ifelse(x < y || (is.na(y) + is.na(x)) == 1, x1, y1)

[1] 8
```

The condition would then return true if `x < y` or if the second argument `y` be `NA`.

Comment: @bicton I edited my answer to cover this, and also gave you an option from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: [It works for me](https://rextester.com/WKSQTL77167).  You must have some other problems in your code.

Comment: It's great and concise! I provide another opinion :  `ifelse(x < y || xor(is.na(y), is.na(x)), x1, y1)`, where `xor` is a logical operator that achieve the same effect as  `is.na(y) + is.na(x)) == 1`.